# Link to open fancybox not working in ios

Tags: jquery, ios, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm having trouble with fancybox on ipad and iphone. The link that should open the lightbox sometimes is not responding. The link css is reset and the lightbox is not showing. On desktop browsers it works fine.

I think it has something to do with screen size, zoom level on the ios device and how fancybox determines the size and position of the box. I've noticed that if I reload the page the link sometimes works. After I've zoomed in the link does not work anymore.

I'm out of options, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Damn me and my dyslexia.. I checked out desktop chrome and firefox **multiple times** without any problems, then came back to this question and realized that you clearly stated that the problem comes up in ios and not at all in desktop browsers.. || **Anyways**, checked it out in my ipod touch and sure enough, nothing happened. Initial thoughts: Use the safari web inspector to check out what console has to say. Set a callback to the fancybox plugin and put `console.log('test')` inside the callback to see if it triggers in ios at all. http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

Comment: Another thought that comes to mind is: Try to isolate the link and the realated code. Strip down the code in stages until the problem goes away.. Or just straight away test it with a clean document to see if it works in ios in the first place ( By clean document, I mean just the essential parts of the link and fancybox ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's neither an iOS or a fancybox issue.

Apart from your validation issues like

```
Mismatch between Public and System identifiers in the DOCTYPE declaration
```

... because you have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

... when you should have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

... (if you can see the difference) you also have some lines that make fancybox conflict with iOS in your http://creactor.nl/script/javascript.js file :

```
var myLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < myLinks.length; i++){
   myLinks[i].addEventListener('touchstart', function(){this.className = "hover";}, false);
   myLinks[i].addEventListener('touchend', function(){this.className = "";}, false);
}
```

I am not an expert in iOS so I can't tell you how to re-write these lines but if you isolate them, then fancybox will work just fine.

I did a small clean-up to your site, including setting a proper DOCTYPE and reorganizing the scripts order, and commented out those lines above and fancybox works fine (in my iPad).

Check **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LG8hu/show/lite/)**

Comment: Hi JFK, Thanks for the effort! I'll apply your changes and will let you know if it solved the issue.

Comment: Ok, i've changed the code of my website and so far it seems the isue has been resolved. It seems the main culprit was the javascript entry you mentioned. Thanks again!